# Node trusted connection using msnodesqlv8

Tags: sql, node.js, npm, connection

I'm trying to connect to SQL server using msnodesqlv8 driver. Now I'm getting an error (TypeError: sql.connect is not a function) before I try to connect with msql driver and I got response but I really need to use a trusted connection.
my code:

```
    var express = require('express');
    var app = express();

    app.get('/', function (req, res) {


    var sql = require("msnodesqlv8");
    console.log(sql);
    // config for your database
    var config = {
        server: 'sqlServername', 
        database: 'myTestDatabase',
        driver: "msnodesqlv8",
        options: {
          trustedConnection: true
        } 
    };

    // connect to your database
    sql.connect(config, function (err) {

        if (err) console.log(err);

        // create Request object
        var request = new sql.Request();

        // query to the database and get the records
        request.query('select * from myTable', function (err, recordset) {

            if (err) console.log(err)

            // send records as a response
            res.send(recordset);

        });
    });
});

    var server = app.listen(5000, function () {
        console.log('Server is running..');
    });
```

Is there any other driver I can use trusted connection? 
I'm using sql server 12.0.4237.0

I try this as well

```
    const sql = require('mssql/msnodesqlv8');
const config = {
    user: "xxxxxxxx",
    password: "xxxxxxxxx",
    domain: "xxxxxxx.com",    
    server: 'hubuddb66',
    database: 'KSheduler',
    pool: {
        max: 10,
        min: 0,
        idleTimeoutMillis: 30000        
    },
    options: {
        trustedConnection: true
      } 
}


sql.connect(config)
.then(conn => console.log("Success!"))
.catch(err => console.log("error! " + err));
```

I receive this error:

ConnectionError: [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0][SQL Server]Login failed for user 'domainxxx\userxxxx'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Read the [documentation](https://github.com/TimelordUK/node-sqlserver-v8#prepared-statements); there is no such function.

You're looking for `sql.open()`.

Comment: I still did not manage to connect with it. Do you think that msnodesqlv8 is the best driver to use @SLaks?

Comment: @CarlosMartins: Why not? What happened?

Answer (score 3):

If you're trying to connect to MySQL server you can use Sequelizejs you can find the documentation [here](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/), If you're trying to connect to MSSQl using msnodesqlv8 you can use `sql.open(connStr, callback(err, conn))`. you can find examples [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/msnodesqlv8).

In both cases make sure your MySQL or MSSQL servers are running.
You can also use Sequelizejs to connect to MSSQL.

Comment: I just edit my question removing "my" word for not create confusion with mySQL. I'm trying to connect to MS SQL server

Comment: You can use Sequelizejs for MS SQL too.

Answer (score 0):

For me changing this condition from 'No' to **'Yes'** worked:

```
switch (key) {
  case 'instance':
    return this.config.options.instanceName
  case 'trusted':
    return this.config.options.trustedConnection ? 'Yes' : 'Yes'
```

It just doesn't load the value from the options object even if I provide it.

I hardcoded this change in file **\node_modules\mssql\lib\msnodesqlv8\connection-pool.js**